# Dropzone.js - Setting Basic Parameters

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am trying to implement `Dropzone.js` into a custom CMS. I have no problems processing the files as needed in PHP, that's actually the easy part.

I need to know how to do the following on a page-by-page basis (will use the dropzone script in several pages for different functions):

1. Restrict the files types (jpg,jpeg,pdf)
2. Restrict the number of files that can be uploaded (some pages will
   just be one file, some will be up to 100)
3. Restrict the Max File Size
4. Redirect the page or have a 'next' button/link appear when the file
   upload is complete.

Can I add this at the bottom of the page, while addressing the settings:

```
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/dropzone/dropzone.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   // initiate layout and plugins
   Metronic.init(); // init metronic core components
   Layout.init(); // init current layout
   Demo.init(); // init demo features
   FormDropzone.init();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="my-dropzone"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var initDropzone = function( filesAllowed ){

    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

      paramName: "file", 
      uploadMultiple: true,
      maxFiles: filesAllowed, //this will need to be set upon init,
      acceptedFiles: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'application/pdf'],
      complete: function() {
          alert('Your file was successfully uploaded!');
      }

    };
}

//init the dropzone
initDropzone( 4 );
```